# php-echo doesn't stop after semicolon

Tags: php, echo

this is a noob question.A very big noob question.
I'm trying echo something,using notepad++ to code.

```
<!DOCTPYE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "<h2>PHP is fun!</h2>";
echo "Hello world!<br>";
echo "I'm about to learn PHP!<br>";
echo "This", " string", " was", " made", " with multiple parameters.";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But what I get is this:

```
PHP is fun!"; echo "Hello world!

"; echo "I'm about to learn PHP!

"; echo "This", " string", " was", " made", " with multiple parameters."; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Works properly for me](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QYzBLc)

Comment: You need to make sure that PHP is installed and it recognize your script as PHP.

Comment: your not just viewing the raw file in the browser are you?

Comment: are you running it on a web server properly?

Comment: Just to be sure, have you saved you file as .php ?

Comment: Do a "view source" of your page in your browser. You'll see the raw PHP code, which means your server is misconfigured.

Comment: What web server are you using? Have you configured it to handle PHP files properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this result because you are running from  Notepad++ `Run -> Launch in Browser.`

This is wrong. Use any web server to make it work. It will not just started working by merely launching the page in browser.

For basic start you can try `Wamp Server`.

Comment: Wamp Server helped. Most obliged.

Comment: If your problem solved then you can mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have a proper PHP configuration at your server.

If you open the file without an installation and configuration from your webserver. The server will deliver it as a plaintext file.

If you simply open the file from the filesystem it will show the page in plaintext or as html file.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer but I had exactly the same issue and spent 1 hour to find out what was wrong. But the answers given here didn't help me. So if someone else have the same issue too, I give the fix I made :
Check your php tag, mine was wrong, I wrote

```
<? php
```

instead of

```
<?php
```